# Wordpress: Fire Verification mail when user signup using MemberMouse

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a Wordpress developer using a plugin called MemberMouse and got a task that whenever a user signup using MemberMouse sign up form it fires an verification email to the new registered user.

I was asked to do it with the smart tags provided by MemberMouse.

As I read out the plugin's documentation I do not find any smart tag that perform this type of action. Is there any way to make this verification thing work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to figure it out myself. It could only be done by writing a custom code for it in Wordpress that triggers mail after user becomes a Member.